AWS beanstalk nodejs application failing with 5xx error
I have a nodejs application running on AWS Elastic Beanstalk. I am using Nginx server. I have used load balancer as well. From a last few hours, my app goes from :
'Environment health has transitioned from Ok to Degraded. 14.3 % of the requests are failing with HTTP 5xx.'
After a minute I'll get :
'Environment health has transitioned from Degraded to Ok.'
I downloaded the logs file from Beanstalk.- logs/RequestLogs/Download full logs. I can't find anything in that. How to stop these 5xx errors? Where can I find the trouble?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
